# Previous and current state are equal in componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

In a dashboard for each module its layout data (using react-grid-layout) is stored separately from the module data and each of them is stored in a database. Current module data and layout data are stored in the Dashboard component state. I am trying to call separate axios POST requests inside `componentDidMount()` whenever the previous state of the modules or the layouts differ from the current ones in order to save the changes in the database. But with debugging and logging, I see that `prevState` equals `this.state`.

Here are the methods that change the related states and the `componentDidMount()` method:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
// JSON.stringify comparison for proof of concept since the order does not change
        if(JSON.stringify(prevState.modules) !== JSON.stringify(this.state.modules))
            API.post('Adminusers/StoreUserModuleData', "module_data=" + JSON.stringify(this.state.modules))
                        .then((res) => console.log(res))
                        .catch(err => {throw new Error(err)});
        if(JSON.stringify(prevState.layouts) !== JSON.stringify(this.state.layouts))
            API.post('Adminusers/StoreAdminUserLayouts', "layouts=" + JSON.stringify(this.state.layouts))
                        .then((res) => console.log(res))
                        .catch(err => {throw new Error(err)});  
    }

addNewModuleInLayout(moduleData) {

        let newLayout = this.state.layouts;
        let newModule = this.state.modules;

        for (let key in newLayout) {
            if (newLayout.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                newLayout[key].push({
                    i: moduleData.type,
                    x: (newLayout[key].length * 1) % 3,
                    y: Infinity,
                    w: 1,
                    h: 5
                });
            }
        }

        newModule.push(moduleData);

        this.setState({layouts: newLayout, modules: newModule})
    }

removeModule(layoutId, type) {
        let newLayout = this.state.layouts;
        let newModule = this.state.modules;

        for (let key in newLayout)
            newLayout[key] = newLayout[key].filter(item => { return item.i !== layoutId })

        newModule = newModule.filter(item => {return item.type != type}); 

        this.setState({ modules: newModule, layouts: newLayout });
    }
```

An example of a module data and layout data for a certain module would be:

```
// layouts
{
 "md": [{ i: "current-user", x: 0, y: 0, w: 3, h: 5, isDraggable: false, isResizable: true }],
 "lg": [{ i: "current-user", x: 0, y: 0, w: 3, h: 5, isDraggable: false, isResizable: true }],
 "sm": [{ i: "current-user", x: 0, y: 0, w: 3, h: 5, isDraggable: false, isResizable: true }],
 "xs": [{ i: "current-user", x: 0, y: 0, w: 3, h: 5, isDraggable: false, isResizable: true }]
}

// module data
[{ type: "current-user", content: " ", title: "Current User Module" }]
```

Could anyone guide on what am I doing wrong here that both states are equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try updating your array declarations in both `addNewModuleInLayout` and `removeModule` to

```
const newLayout = { ...this.state.layouts }; // from let newLayout = this.state.layouts
const newModule = [...this.state.modules]; // from let newModule = this.state.modules
```

in cDM you don't create a "new" copy of your module/layout arrays on state, but rather reference the arrays directly.  when you update the arrays you actually mutate your state, so when you diff `prevState` with `this.state` the stringified versions are equal.

this won't deeply copy your layouts object though so you will run into the same issue when pushing to your layout arrays.  you might be able to get around this by creating a new array when updating a layout instead of pushing

```
newLayout[key] = [
 ...newLayout[key], 
 {
   i: moduleData.type,
   x: (newLayout[key].length * 1) % 3,
   y: Infinity,
   w: 1,
   h: 5
 }
]; // from newLayout[key].push({DATA}); in addNewModuleInLayout
```

since you use `filter` in `removeModule` you should be good there

Comment: Right. But on the `let newLayout = [...this.state.layouts]` i get an error since that is an object that has array properties...

Comment: sorry I didn't see that `layouts` was an object.  could you get away with a shallow copy of the layout object via `let newLayout = {...this.state.layouts}`?

Comment: As it seems, i cannot get away with that. It does not work 100% of the time when i try to add or remove a module (trying to change state)

Comment: modules or layouts?  it makes sense that layout updates don't work since you don't deeply copy the object and thus have the same issue when referencing layout arrays on the shallow copy.  I just updated my comment with a workaround for this though.  let me know if that does the trick 

Comment: Yes, this way the states are different. But this gave life to some other hidden problems :P another question will ensue, but as far as this question is concerned, all is good